# React Native Project Run Real Device with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

My problem is this:
I created a project in React Native 0.59.9.

I can run the project on all simulators in Xcode.

But I can't run it on my ios device.

When I press "Run" the project is compiled and the Metro Bundler is running, but "Loading dependency graph, done." also hangs out.

After a while, the application starts on the phone, but "dev settings" does not connect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the project from within Xcode. You will likely find some settings and/or errors in Xcode which will need to be resolved.

Comment: I'm running the project with Xcode. It works on the simulator. But it doesn't work on the real device.

Comment: I'm not in front of xcode but is the device you're trying to use provisioned in xcode?

Comment: It works on all iOS simulators. But when I run it on my device, the Metro Bundler gets stuck on the "loading dependency graph, done" warning.